# Riddle me this: Why is onEdit only triggering on edits made in ranges I apparently never even defined? Or did I?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

TLDR: Why does the last 'if' statement in my example NOT work, while the 'if' statement just before/above it DOES work?

Why is onEdit ONLY triggering when edits are made in certain ranges? The ranges where it DOES trigger strangely correspond to a set of values I've stored in 8 arrays.

Disclaimer/apologies: brand new to coding, google apps script & sheets

My script starts with a bunch of global variables as follows. Notice in particular the "centre#Range" variables which are arrays I use later for defining useful ranges. In my opinion it is these variables which seem to somehow define ranges for where the onEdit function will trigger. Edits anywhere else, furthermore on other sheets, do not seem to trigger onEdit?? onEdit only seems to be triggering if I make an edit within any of the ranges apparently defined by the "centre#Range" variables. What am I missing here?

'''

```
var yieldManSSName = "yieldMan";
var optionsWsName = "options";
var yieldCalSSName = "yieldCal";
var resManSSName = "resMan";
var wsOptionsName = 'granary';

var optionsVillageFilterColumn = 0;
var optionsTownFilterColumn = 1;
var optionsTerrainColumn = 2;
var optionsFreshWaterColumn = 3;
var optionsVeinColumn = 4;
var optionsYielderColumn = 5;
var optionsWellColumn = 6;
var optionsWorkersColumn = 7;
var optionsDefaultYieldColumn = 8;
var optionsDefaultTypeColumn = 9;
var optionsYielderYieldColumn = 10;
var optionsYielderTypeColumn = 11;
var optionsWaterYieldColumn = 12;
var optionsWaterTypeColumn = 13;

var yieldManSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(yieldManSSName);
var resManSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(resManSSName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow() - 1, 16).getValues();
var yieldCalSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(yieldCalSSName);

var optionsBlankCell = wsOptions.getRange('O3');
var optionsYieldTokens = wsOptions.getRange('O4:O16');
var optionsTerrainsList = wsOptions.getRange(2, 3, wsOptions.getLastRow() - 1);

var yMCentre1Terrain1CellRow = 5;

//centre#Range = [top row, bottom row, left-most column, right-most column]; NOTE: top row = the row above the table
// these arrays seem to correspond with the ranges in which onEdit is triggering??
var centre1Range = [2, 10, 1, 9];
var centre2Range = [12, 20, 1, 9];
var centre3Range = [22, 30, 1, 9];
var centre4Range = [32, 40, 1, 9];
var centre5Range = [42, 50, 1, 9];
var centre6Range = [52, 60, 1, 9];
var centre7Range = [62, 70, 1, 9];
var centre8Range = [72, 80, 1, 9];

var centrePosition = [centre1Range, centre2Range, centre3Range, centre4Range, centre5Range, centre6Range, centre7Range, centre8Range];

var yMcentre1NameRow = 3;
var yMcentre2NameRow = 13;
var yMcentre3NameRow = 23;
var yMcentre4NameRow = 33;
var yMcentre5NameRow = 43;
var yMcentre6NameRow = 53;
var yMcentre7NameRow = 63;
var yMcentre8NameRow = 73;

function onEdit(e) {

  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedCellVal = editedCell.getValue();
  var r = editedCell.getRow();
  var c = editedCell.getColumn();
  var editedCellWsName = editedCell.getSheet().getName();

  // this loop determines in which predefined table range (ranges defined above) an edit occurs and then delegates a corresponding reference cell for that table. "cTopRow" = centreTopRow; etc. 
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (r >= centrePosition[i][0] && r <= centrePosition[i][1] && c >= centrePosition[i][2] && c <= centrePosition[1][3]) {
      var cTopRow = centrePosition[i][0];
      var cBottomRow = centrePosition[i][1];
      var cLeftColumn = centrePosition[i][2];
      var cRightColumn = centrePosition[i][3];
    }
  }

  // "yMTokenC" stands for yieldManTokenColumn where yieldMan is the name of the sheet, short for Yield Manager; just so you know
  var yMTokenColumn = cLeftColumn;
  var yMCentreTypeCol = cLeftColumn + 1;
  var yMTerrainColumn = cLeftColumn + 1;
  var yMFreshWaterColumn = cLeftColumn + 2;
  var yMVeinColumn = cLeftColumn + 3;
  var yMYielderColumn = cLeftColumn + 4;
  var yMWellColumn = cLeftColumn + 5;
  var yMWorkersColumn = cLeftColumn + 6;
  var yMYieldColumn = cLeftColumn + 7;

  var yMCentreTypeRow = cTopRow + 1;
  var centreTypeCell = yieldManSS.getRange(yMCentreTypeRow, yMCentreTypeCol);
  var centreTypeVal = centreTypeCell.getValue();

  var line1 = cTopRow + 3;

  if (c === 9) { // notice 9 falls within the range of the arrays above
    yieldManSS.getRange('A1').setValue('This one works!');
  }
  if (c === 10) { // notice 10 falls beyond the range of the arrays above
    yieldManSS.getRange('A1').setValue('This one does not seem to even trigger onEdit?!');
}
```

'''

Comment: You're making a lot of function calls for data that is already in the event object which consumes more time for no extra value.

Comment: The reality is that I'm not going to take the time to go through your code and figure out what it does because it looks fairly complex.  If you wish to explain, I might read that but I'm interested in debugging your code the reality is that onEdit trigger fire on every user edit.  These triggers will not perform functions that require permission and the functions must complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: That's fair enough. Most of the code I included is only there for evidence. I suppose my core/specific question is this: Why does the last 'if' statement in my example NOT work, while the 'if' statement just before/above it DOES work? If what you say about the onEdit trigger is true, then I believe the latter "if" statement should work and setValue the same as the one above it, but it simply doesn't. In fact, the only places where the onEdit trigger seems to fire in my sheet mysteriously correspond with the values in the 8 arrays at the top of my code, hence its inclusion in my question

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

**The onEdit trigger**

The onEdit trigger fires whenever a user makes an edit anywhere in any sheet.  If you want something special to happen in certain ranges you can use conditional logic to identify it and return for everything else.  If you don't have an onEdit() function then nothing happens on the trigger.

If you need to do something that requires permissions then you need to use an installable trigger.  And you can create those through the triggers menu or programmatically with `ScriptApp.newTrigger()`

[onEdit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

If you want to see more of the onEdit Event Object.  Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('onEdit trigger');
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Event Object Stringified:

```
{"value":"\\","source":{},"range":{"columnEnd":9,"columnStart":9,"rowEnd":7,"rowStart":7},"authMode":"LIMITED","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}
```

> I use `e.source.toast('flags');` a lot whenevere I'm debugging them and I usually debug them while they are running on a sheet.  Although you can use an intermediate function to call them as long a you supply the event object as shown above.

Comment: "The onEdit trigger fires whenever a user makes an edit anywhere in any sheet."
But that's just it, Cooper, I believe that it's ONLY firing when an edit is made within certain ranges; ranges I've apparently inadvertently set, but have no idea how? Look at the last two "if" statements in my example code. Cheers!

Comment: Try making my onEdit(e) the only onEdiit in the project and edit any page and you'll see that it fires anywhere.  You see when it fires because you will get a toast that says onEdit trigger. The ranges that you specify anywhere have no bearing on the generation of onEdit triggers.

Comment: I appreciate your support. I'm not familiar with the toast thing you mention, but I'll look it up & try it. Otherwise, I only have the one onEdit(e) function in the script. Albeit it's a long function with many conditions to trigger other functions. But if I make an edit ANYWHERE outside of the "ranges" suggested by the numbers in my arrays, it does not trigger. Bizarre. I can't explain it. Guess that's why I'm here : )

Comment: There's a simple trigger that runs functions named onEdit  the trigger fires whenever a user makes and edit.  The functions normally conditional logic that control their behavior so that when certain conditions are met your function will perform the way you wish.  It's not really correct to say that the trigger doesn't fire on a user edit.  Another thing you should be aware of is that all functions that are tied to a simple onEdit trigger must complete within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In your onEdit() function you are starting with a loop that checks if e.range is in a certain range, if so, set the values of the variables within the if statement.

**2)** Your code has a lot of unreferenced variables in it.  Not sure if they will be used later, but as is they seem extraneous.

**3)** Running a loop on every edit uses a lot of resources.  Use a set of conditions first, then run your loop and other code.  Use conditional logic to define which cells will run your code when they are edited.

For example, if you want to only run the code if a cell in one of your centreRanges is edited. Since the columns are always between 1 and 9, and the row will fall between 2 and 80, you can limit the loop to only run if the edited cell is within that larger dataset range.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedCellVal = e.value; //you can access the event value directly
  var r = editedCell.getRow();
  var c = editedCell.getColumn();
  var editedCellWsName = editedCell.getSheet().getName();

  
  // check if the cell is within your overall data set
  if(c >=1 && c <= 9 && r >= 2 && r <= 80){

    //do your stuff in here
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Good feedback thanks; I will implement this change
2) I have only provided a snapshot of the entire script. Most of those variables are referenced elsewhere; however, it could still use a bit of a cleanup : )
3) Good feedback; I will make this change.

-I believe the question still stands, though. To ask more specifically: why does my last "if" statement, which demonstrates what I believe to be the mystery, not work, while the statement just before it does? To me it suggests that onEdit() is mysteriously not triggering for some reason when edits are made outside of the above ranges?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I looks like you misspelled get Range() in the last statement.

Comment: Ha! Well spotted! Don't ask me who Ange is, nor why I want to 'get' her lol. However, that typo is not in the actual script as I did not copy & paste it here, I typed example 'if' statements to illustrate what's happening. Just to be sure, I've gone back and crosschecked the 2 similar statements in the actual script & am certain they are free of any such errors. Therefore, I believe the question still stands...